# Map list item to function with arguments

Tags: python

Is there any way to map list items to a function along with arguments?

I have a list:

```
pages = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5...]
```

And I have to call function `myFunc` corresponding to each list elements along with additional arguments such that the following can be computed

```
myFunc(p1, additionalArgument)
myFunc(p2, additionalArgument)
```

and so on...

Is there any elegant method for doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Python map() function with keyword arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499824/using-python-map-function-with-keyword-arguments)

Comment: @LondonRob The question was asked before the one you provided link for.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
result = [myFunc(p, additionalArgument) for p in pages]
```

Comment: Once read, obviously elegant (with the side effect to never use `map()` again...)

Comment: @AdN: `map` has its uses. `map(f, lst)` is less repetitive than `[f(x) for x in lst]`.

Comment: Why not a simple loop? Seriously? Why complicate things?
for p in pages:
  myFunc(p, additionalArgument)

Comment: @AFP_555 speed. A `for` loop is several orders of magnitude slower than mapping. This matters when you're working with millions of objects.

Comment: @JosephFarah No, the for loop isn't slower, and certainly not by several orders of magnitude. Why would it be? If you need a list of the results of the function calls, use the list comprehension. If you just want to call the functions, use a for loop.

Comment: @SvenMarnach will remove. I made the comment when I was less experienced and thought a single test was conclusive. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @AFP_555 While this is a very long time after the fact, map is very useful for tensors where you can't use for loops.

Answer (score 132):

You can also use a lambda function:

```
map(lambda p: myFunc(p, additionalArgument), pages)
```

Comment: why is using map(lambda p: myFunc(p, additionalArgument), pages) superior to [myFunc(p, additionalArgument) for p in pages]? I'd suggest that this is only the case for very simple functions. Would gladly accept comments as I am new to python

Comment: @OldSchool Most people consider list comprehensions to be more idiomatic in Python than using `map()`. Guido even wanted to remove `map()` from the language at some point. However, the community decided to keep it, so it's definitely fine to use if you prefer it. I personally often use it when mapping an existing function over an iterable, but I'd never use `map(lambda:..., ...)`, since this really has no advantage over a list comprehension, and is even slower due to the added function call overhead.

Comment: @Sven, thanks. Makes sense. Leaving `map()` aside, is there any reason to write `[lambda p: myFunc(p, additionalArgument) for p in pages]` rather than just `[myFunc(p,additionalArgument) for p in pages]`?

Comment: @OldSchool Sure, you can write that if you want a list of lambda functions. Note that these lambda funcitons will just be created and stored in the list. They won't be called by the list comprehension. It is unclear to me what you are trying ot achieve.

Comment: @Sven. What I am trying to say is that I don't see the benefit of using the `lambda` keyword if the lambda is just calling `myFunc()`. Might as well just put `myFunc()` in there without wrapping it in a lambda  no?

Comment: @OldSchool You suggested the lambda. I don't think it makes sense to add it to the list comprehension, since you will end up with a list of identical lambda functions that haven't been called. The expression `f(x)` calls the function `f` with arg `x`. The expression `lambda x: f(x)` creates a new lambda function object that can be called later.

Comment: list comprehension is nice, but I consider this is better, as it can be applied to some operations over an array using vectorization and numpy. Let's imagine this example could be applied to an array: np.array(map(lambda p: myFunc(p, additionalArgument), pages))

Answer (score 53):

You could use a list comprehension

```
[myFunc(p, additionalArgument) for p in pages]
```

or `functools.partial()`

```
map(functools.partial(myFunc, some_arg=additionalArgument), pages)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. A list comprehension is more simple while the `map()` function is more faster. The `functools.partial()` method should be used when there's speed requirement. And this version can be also useful to `multiprocessing.pool.map()`.

Comment: @C.K.I don't expect `map(partial(...), ...)` to be faster than a list comprehension, except maybe in a few corner cases. I just added it for completeness and use cases like `pool.map()`. I think the accepted answer is perfectly fine, since the list comprehension is generally considered the most idiomatic solution for this use case. What's beyond me is how on earth the `map(lambda: ..., ...)` answer added years later got voted so highly – it's slower, less succinct and less readable than the list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you're planning to use `map` for **distributed computations** (i.e. using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)) it will not unpack the arguments as one could expect. Say you want to distribute your call to `myFunc` (which accepts two arguments: `page` and `additionalArgument`) with:

```
pages = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5...]
```

If you specify a list of `args` (tuples), i.e.

```
args = [(page, additionalArgument) for page in pages]
```

`map` **will not** unpack the `args` tuple and will pass only one argument (tuple) to `myFunc`:

```
pool.map(myFunc, args)  # map does not unpack the tuple
```

You **will** need to use [multiprocessing.starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) instead

> `starmap` is like `map()` except that the elements of the iterable are expected to be iterables that are unpacked as arguments.

i.e.

```
pool.starmap(myFunc, args)  # tuples are unpacked and two arguments are passed to myFunc
```