# Using map() function with keyword arguments

Tags: python, arguments, map-function

Here is the loop I am trying to use the `map` function on:

```
volume_ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
ip = '172.12.13.122'
for volume_id in volume_ids:
    my_function(volume_id, ip=ip)
```

Is there a way I can do this? It would be trivial if it weren't for the `ip` parameter, but I'm not sure how to deal with that.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

mapfunc = partial(my_function, ip=ip)
map(mapfunc, volume_ids)
```

`partial()` creates a new callable, that'll apply any arguments (including keyword arguments) to the wrapped function in addition to whatever is being passed to that new callable.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a lambda approach (not better, just different)

```
volume_ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
ip = '172.12.13.122'
map(lambda ids: my_function(ids, ip), volume_ids);
```

Comment: partials are faster, lambdas support out of order arguments

Answer (score 12):

This can be done easily with a list comprehension.

```
volume_ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
ip = '172.12.13.122'
results = [my_function(i,ip=ip) for i in volume_ids]
```

Comment: This has side effects. You are assigning a bunch of memory that may not be desired (and wasn't specified by OP).

Comment: @aydow Why didn't you complain about the same thing under the other answers?

Answer (score 3):

In general, one can use map to pass keywords to a function by wrapping that function in something which unpacks a dictionary, and then passing an iterable of dictionaries to map. Example:

```
from itertools import product

volume_ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
volume_ids = (("volume_id", volume_id) for volume_id in volume_ids)
ips = [("ip", '172.12.13.122')]
kwargs_iterable = map(dict, product(volume_ids, ips))

result = map(lambda kwargs: my_function(**kwargs), kwargs_iterable)
```

For your special case, however, a simpler solution would be:

```
map(my_function, volume_ids, [ip]*len(volume_ids))
```

This is concise and does not rely on any imports. Another possibility could be to combine product and starmap from itertools:

```
from itertools import product, starmap

ips = [ip]
starmap(my_function, product(volume_ids, ips))
```

This generalizes nicely to the setting with more than one ip adress, or more than two variables.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
results = []
for volume_id in volume_ids:
    results.append(my_function(volume_id, ip=ip))
```

This is three lines of code instead of one --- it's three lines of clear and obvious code instead of importing some special-case helper from module such-and-such.  This argument is probably a matter of taste, but it has a lot of weight depending on who you talk to.

Comment: The problem is that we want to avoid the for loop

Comment: Why?  Because it's clearer?  Or because of some misconception like "for loops are slow in Python"?

Comment: Yes, I would say indeed is clearer, more Pythonish, and map function is meant to perform the laziest iteration posible. Besides, we need a list  back, so map would perform it better for us than writing more lines coding a for loop