# can I map a "bound" method to a list of instances using map() in python?

Tags: python, functional-programming

The functional `map(func,iterable)` could be easily applied to normal functions, but if I want to apply the `a_method` to a list of instances, how can I do it? I know list comprehensions can do this in a snap, but still want to see if a functional way exist and also feels pythonic.

```
class cls(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val=val
    def clstest(self,val):
        return self.val==val
a=cls(9)
b=cls(18)
c=cls(19)
lst=[a,b,c]
```

Then the following works:`list(map(repr,lst))` returns

```
['<__main__.Cls object at 0x00000000070EDB70>',
 '<__main__.Cls object at 0x00000000070EDBE0>',
 '<__main__.Cls object at 0x00000000070EDE80>']
```

, but `list(map(clstest(10),lst))` will have error msg:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-165-f10396f98b58> in <module>()
----> 1 list(map(clstest,lst))

NameError: name 'clstest' is not defined
```

**Update**: correct my mistake in defining the class. The error msg still remains.

Comment: First of all, `def cls(object)` defines a function called `cls` that takes one parameter called `object`. If you want a class that inherits from `object`, you should go with `class cls(object)`. Secondly, try out `cls.clstest` in  your `map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first word in your code should be *class*, not *def*.
Accepted practices in Python is giving *ClassNames* (**cls** is usually used for class methods). And you indents need fixing.

Here is untetsted full answer

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val=val
    def clstest(self,val):
        return self.val==val

objects = [MyClass(v) for v in (9, 18,19)]
map(lambda o: o.clstest(10), objects)
```

The answer is - yes, you can

Comment: This is very true (and probably just a typo copying into SO), but I'm not convinced it answers OP's question.

Comment: @mhlester, I did not compete for answer - you already provided one. Did you try yours - has it worked with definitions as they are?

Comment: (downvote wasn't me btw). If you're not answering the question, this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: You did neither - with wrong definitions your answer is useless

Comment: @NathaneilCapital, because *clstest* is defined within a boundary of the class. See my edited answer

Comment: @volcano, you're right. I did not realize each of our answers on their own would leave OP with the same error. I apologize.

Comment: @mhlester, an honest mistake :)

Comment: I think this answer and the above `functools.partial` doing the job, both syn taxes are less ideal, lambda probably better.

Comment: @NathaneilCapital, there is nothing wrong with syntax in other two answers - but in simple cases **partial** is an overkill. **partial** approach is extremely useful for callbacks - but creating it on every iteration is extremely wasteful. **methodcaller** (new for me too) is good too. It is especially good when you have common methods for more than one class - or when an object does not expose API explicitly (some specialized packages? I have seen cases like that). In the end of the day, a choice between **lambda** and **methodcaller** is a matter of style

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (with help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499824/using-python-map-function-with-keyword-arguments))

```py
class cls(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val=val
    def clstest(self,val):
        return self.val==val
a=cls(9)
b=cls(10)
c=cls(19)
lst=[a,b,c]
# use functools.partial
from functools import partial
list(map(partial(cls.clstest,val=10),lst))
```

Comment: *partial* is useful when you save references, in this case it's a waste of resources

Comment: A `partial` object is just a wrapper, like a lambda, but with more flexible semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import operator
lst = [ cls(9), cls(18), cls(19) ]
x = operator.methodcaller('clstest', 10)
map( x, lst )
```

The `methodcaller` function creates a callable object that invokes a named method on its argument, so for example `x(lst[0])` is the same as `lst[0].clstest(10)`.

Comment: This will work, but put an '`' to  call the method by name seems not very 'smooth' (pythonic?).

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the function in a `lambda`:

```
list(map(lambda instance: instance.clstest(10), lst))
```

Or as you mentioned, as a list comprehension:

```
[instance.clstest(10) for instance in lst]
```

Also, this line makes me cry: `lst=list([a,b,c])` should just be `lst = [a,b,c]`