# Using the multiprocessing.Pool.map() function with keyword arguments?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to pass the keyword arguments to the `map` function in Python's `multiprocessing.Pool` instance.

Extrapolating from [***Using map() function with keyword arguments***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499824/using-map-function-with-keyword-arguments), I know I can use `functools.partial()` such as the following:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial
import sys

# Function to multiprocess
def func(a, b, c, d):
    print(a * (b + 2 * c - d))
    sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(2)
    # Now, I try to call func(a, b, c, d) for 10 different a values,
    # but the same b, c, d values passed in as keyword arguments
    a_iter = range(10)
    kwargs = {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}

    mapfunc = partial(func, **kwargs)
    p.map(mapfunc, a_iter)
```

The output is correct:

```
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
```

Is this the best practice (most "pythonic" way) to do so? I felt that:

1) `Pool` is commonly used;

2) Keyword arguments are commonly used;

3) But the combined usage like my example above is a little bit like a "hacky" way to achieve this.

Comment: Seems fine to me. map only takes positional parameters, so using partial to create a suitable function object is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Does it works only if iterable argument  is FIRST in function defenition? I mean if I want use map for argument `b` I need to swap them in function defenition? Because I have an error if just define `a` key in `kwargs` and drop `b` from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `partial` may be suboptimal if the default arguments are large. The function passed to `map` is repeatedly `pickle`-ed when sent to the workers (once for every argument in  the iterable); a global Python function is (essentially) `pickle`-ed by sending the qualified name (because the same function is defined on the other side without needing to transfer any data) while `partial` is `pickle`-ed as the `pickle` of the function and all the provided arguments.

If `kwargs` is all small primitives, as in your example, this doesn't really matter; the incremental cost of sending along the extra arguments is trivial. But if `kwargs` is big, say, `kwargs = {'b': [1] * 10000, 'c': [2] * 20000, 'd': [3]*30000}`, that's a nasty price to pay.

In that case, you have some options:

1. Roll your own function at the global level that works like `partial`, but `pickle`s differently:

   ```
   class func_a_only(a):
       return func(a, 1, 2, 3)
   ```
2. Using the `initializer` argument to `Pool` so each worker process sets up state once, instead of once per task, allowing you to ensure data is available even if you're working in spawn based environment (e.g. Windows)
3. Using `Manager`s to share a single copy of data among all processes

And probably a handful of other approaches. Point is, `partial` is fine for arguments that don't produce huge `pickle`s, but it can kill you if the bound arguments are huge.

Note: In this particular case, if you're in Python 3.3+, you don't actually *need* `partial`, and avoiding the `dict` in favor of `tuple`s saves a trivial amount of overhead. Without adding any new functions, just some imports, you could replace:

```
kwargs = {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
mapfunc = partial(func, **kwargs)
p.map(mapfunc, a_iter)
```

with:

```
from itertools import repeat

p.starmap(func, zip(a_iter, repeat(1), repeat(2), repeat(3)))
```

to achieve a similar effect. To be clear, there is nothing wrong with `partial` that this "fixes" (both approaches would have the same problem with pickling large objects), this is just an alternate approach that is occasionally useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When you mention that I don't really need `partial` in Python >= 3.3, where I do not need to avoid dict in favor of tuples, do you mean that I can use `Pool.apply_async()` instead? I assume that if I use `Pool.map()`, I can only use iterables like a tuple or list (`pool.map(func, iterable)`) and can't use a dict (`pool.apply_async(func, args, kwargs)`). Was I getting it right?

Comment: @ShawnWang: I was referring to the ability to use `Pool.starmap` instead of `Pool.map`, allowing you to use `zip` to construct a `tuple` of arguments that `starmap` unpacks for you. That alternative is what I'm demonstrating in the final code block, providing repetitive values for `b`, `c`, and `d` positionally by using `repeat` and `zip` to construct the complete set of positional arguments over and over instead of using keyword arguments at all.