# Raising elements of a list to a power

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

How can I raise the numbers in list to a certain power?

Comment: What didn't work? What was the actual output you got?

Comment: my_list[i]=my_list[i]**3 modify your original list.

Comment: I think the question lacks details. Those which were deleted in the edit might be a start....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
def power(my_list):
    return [ x**3 for x in my_list ]
```

https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 5):

Another `map` pattern, using `lambda` instead of `function.partial()`:

```
numbers=[1,2,3,4]
squares=list(map(lambda x:pow(x,2),numbers))
print(squares)
```

Answer (score 4):

Nobody has mentioned [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and the accepted answer does not mention [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow), but for the sake of completeness I am posting this solution:

```
import functools
bases = numbers = [1,2,3]
power = exponent = 3
cubed = list(map(functools.partial(pow, exponent), numbers))
```

I would use a list comprehension myself as suggested, but I think `functools.partial` is a very cool function that deserves to be shared. I stole my answer from @sven-marnach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212445/python-map-list-item-to-function-with-arguments#10212475) by the way.

Comment: can you explain more ?  what does have functools.partial good point?

Answer (score 2):

```
def turn_to_power(list, power=1): 
    return [number**power for number in list]
```

Example:

```
   list = [1,2,3]
   turn_to_power(list)
=> [1, 2, 3]
   turn_to_power(list,2)
=> [1, 4, 9]
```

UPD: you should also consider reading about `pow(x,y)` function of `math` lib: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/math.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
numbers3 = []
for n in numbers:
    numbers3.append(n**3)

print('Original list:', numbers)
print('Cubic list:', numbers3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your script do what you want, and that is the result (keep in mind that you are applying the power function to [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

('Cubic list:', [1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729])

Your problem is that you also modified the original list, due to the nature on the list type in python. If you want to keep also your original list you should pass a copy of it to your function. You can do it like this

```
def main():
    numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    numbers3=power(numbers[:])
    print('Original list:', numbers)
    print('Cubic list:', numbers3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension for some increased speed:

```
print('Original list:', numbers)
print('Cubic list:', [n**3 for n in numbers])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(list(map(pow,numbers,repeat(2)))
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to how this works, and use the code formatting tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a random list by taking an input from the user, lets call that 'n'
and squared the numbers in the list.

```
n = int(input("Enter a number"))
list1 = [*range(0,n,1)]
list2 = [number ** 2 for number in list1]
```