# Raising elements of a list to powers indicated in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to raise my list [23, 43, 32, 27, 11] to the powers indicated in this list [3, 5, 4, 3, 2].

Meanding the 23 should be raised to the power of 3, 43 to the power of 5 etc...

I can do the whole list to one power with the help of this question: [Raising elements of a list to a power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323439/raising-elements-of-a-list-to-a-power) but not like how I need.

Should I use two loops? Many thanks for the help.

Comment: `[ x**y for x,y in zip([23,43,32,27,11],[3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2]) ]`

Comment: Yes there was a extra 2 in the 2nd list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [**`zip()`**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> a = [23, 43, 32, 27, 11]
>>> b = [3, 5, 4, 3, 2]
>>> c = [x**y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
>>> c
[12167, 147008443, 1048576, 19683, 121]
```

or [**`map()`**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map) and [**`operator.pow()`**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> from operator import pow
>>> d = list(map(pow, a, b))
>>> d
[12167, 147008443, 1048576, 19683, 121]
```

Comment: Any chance I can convince you to reverse the order of those two suggestions (`zip` above `map`)?

Comment: Sure will do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([23, 43, 32, 27, 11])
e = np.array([3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2])

# constrain sizes (like zip)
m = min(b.shape[0], e.shape[0])
b = b[:m]
e = e[:m]

print(b**e)            # 1. typical method
print(np.power(b, e))  # 2. you might like this better in some scenarios
```

Comment: Downvoted due to: (i) there is currently no `e` defined (its `p`); and (ii) the solution surely can't work as the arrays are **different lengths**.  (and `numpy` is a very heavyweight dependency to answer a simple question)

Comment: @donkopotamus `numpy` is the canonical solution for anyone working with numerical data. At the very least, those who have this particular question might consider it.