# insert argument to map function python

Tags: python

I have a following function:

```py
def calculate_frequent_itemset(fractional_data, support):
    """Function that calculated the frequent dataset parallely"""
    return apriori(fractional_data, min_support=support, use_colnames=True)
```

I would like to call it in a map function using:

```py
frequent_itemsets=p.map(calculate_frequent_itemset,(dataNew1,dataNew2,dataNew3,dataNew4,dataNew5), 200)
```

In other words I want to set 200 as support argument. But I got an error `TypeError: calculate_frequent_itemset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'support'`. How can I fix it please?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10834960/10197418

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wrapper function (or a lambda):

```py
support=200
def my_calculate_frequent_itemset(fractional_data):
    return calculate_frequent_itemset(fractional_data, support)

frequent_itemsets=p.map(my_calculate_frequent_itemset,(dataNew1,dataNew2,dataNew3,dataNew4,dataNew5))
```

It's pretty horrible.

I rediscovered this - rather perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31995624/1021819 which gives the same answer

Comment: Does not work, same error.

Comment: @vojta https://stackoverflow.com/a/31995624/1021819 does not work for you?

Comment: @MrFuppes Edited to remove lambda (no longer seems elegant / worth it..)